# PhpStorm: notebook often hangs up upon displaying context menu in working area

Tags: phpstorm, freeze

I'm troubling for about a year with frequent hangs of my notebook at the moment of displaying context menus in PhpStorm while coding in main window area. Mainly it happens when I press Alt+Enter and sometimes when using mouse.

Every time I have to switch my notebook off and on to reboot, boot up my docker containers and all other resources to continue. Moreover, phpStorm doesn't store my editing and I have to begin from early steps until next hang.

I don't know if it caused by some plugin or some bug inside IDE itself but these hangs make my work a Sisyphean labour.

[image]

Have anybody faced the same problem? Any help is appreciated.

It doesn't matter what version of PhpStorm I use. For now it is `2023.2.3` (Debian 12).

Comment: With this kinds of questions you better contact JetBrains Support directly -- just use `Main menu | Help | Contact Support...` where you can privately provide all requested information (e.g. IDE logs / Java crash dumps etc).  **P.S.** What I may suggest to do in the meantime -- run the MemTest (you have hanging and not crashing here but anyway) -- a decent chance that this could be a hardware issue...